# API calls don't run when I codesign my Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, app-store

I'm trying to sign my Mac OS X for Mac Store deployment but when I sign my bundle app, it doesn't make network calls.

The app has been developed in cpp using Qt

**PKG generation steps**

This is my script to codesign the app

***Integrate the frameworks inside binary***

```
macdeployqt MyAppName.app
```

***Check if everything when ok***

```
dsymutil MyAppName.app/Contents/MacOS/MyAppName -o MyAppName.app.dSYM
```

***Sign Frameworks***

```
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtDBus.framework/Versions/5/QtDBus 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/bearer/libqcorewlanbearer.dylib 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/bearer/libqgenericbearer.dylib 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/imageformats/libq*
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib 
codesign --entitlements ../myappame_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app/Contents/PlugIns/printsupport/libcocoaprintersupport.dylib
```

(until this step, the App runs pretty well)

***Sign bundle app***

```
codesign --deep --entitlements ../myappname_desktop/MyAppName.entitlements -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: MyAppName" MyAppName.app
```

***Generate PKG***

```
productbuild --component MyAppName.app /Applications --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: MyAppName" MyAppName.pkg
```

**MyAppName.entitlements**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**MyAppName.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MyAppName</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.myappname.desktop</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSUIElement</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>ForAppStore</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.productivity</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

**Bundle structure**

```
MyAppName.app
└── Contents
    ├── Frameworks
    │   ├── QtCore.framework
    │   │   ├── QtCore -> Versions/Current/QtCore
    │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    │   │   └── Versions
    │   │       ├── 5
    │   │       │   ├── QtCore
    │   │       │   └── Resources
    │   │       │       └── Info.plist
    │   │       └── Current -> 5
    │   ├── QtDBus.framework
    │   │   ├── QtDBus -> Versions/Current/QtDBus
    │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    │   │   └── Versions
    │   │       ├── 5
    │   │       │   ├── QtDBus
    │   │       │   └── Resources
    │   │       │       └── Info.plist
    │   │       └── Current -> 5
    │   ├── QtGui.framework
    │   │   ├── QtGui -> Versions/Current/QtGui
    │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    │   │   └── Versions
    │   │       ├── 5
    │   │       │   ├── QtGui
    │   │       │   └── Resources
    │   │       │       └── Info.plist
    │   │       └── Current -> 5
    │   ├── QtNetwork.framework
    │   │   ├── QtNetwork -> Versions/Current/QtNetwork
    │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    │   │   └── Versions
    │   │       ├── 5
    │   │       │   ├── QtNetwork
    │   │       │   └── Resources
    │   │       │       └── Info.plist
    │   │       └── Current -> 5
    │   ├── QtPrintSupport.framework
    │   │   ├── QtPrintSupport -> Versions/Current/QtPrintSupport
    │   │   ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    │   │   └── Versions
    │   │       ├── 5
    │   │       │   ├── QtPrintSupport
    │   │       │   └── Resources
    │   │       │       └── Info.plist
    │   │       └── Current -> 5
    │   └── QtWidgets.framework
    │       ├── QtWidgets -> Versions/Current/QtWidgets
    │       ├── Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources
    │       └── Versions
    │           ├── 5
    │           │   ├── QtWidgets
    │           │   └── Resources
    │           │       └── Info.plist
    │           └── Current -> 5
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── Hightrack
    ├── PkgInfo
    ├── PlugIns
    │   ├── bearer
    │   │   ├── libqcorewlanbearer.dylib
    │   │   └── libqgenericbearer.dylib
    │   ├── imageformats
    │   │   ├── libqdds.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqgif.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqicns.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqico.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqjp2.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqjpeg.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqmng.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqtga.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqtiff.dylib
    │   │   ├── libqwbmp.dylib
    │   │   └── libqwebp.dylib
    │   ├── platforms
    │   │   └── libqcocoa.dylib
    │   └── printsupport
    │       └── libcocoaprintersupport.dylib
    └── Resources
        ├── empty.lproj
        ├── icon.icns
        └── qt.conf
```

Comment: @KubaOber yes it copy the QtNetwork inside my bundle. I have edited my question with my bundle structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outgoing network access requires the `com.apple.security.network.client` entitlement be added to your entitlements file. See [App Sandbox Entitlement Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html) for the full list.

Comment: I have the same problem when I create a file inside ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ to allow autolaunch my app. I have tried these two entitlements but it doesn't run `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` and  `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.executable`

Comment: If you're just trying to launch your app (rather than a separate background daemon), you may want to add a Login Item rather than a launch agent: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html